# Joining PostgreSQL views with selects

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a couple of views in PostgreSQL that return tables like these:

```
tickets_new

| id | queue | owner | subject  | status |       created       |
| -- | ----- | ----- | -------- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 1  | 1     | 123   | Subject1 | new    | 2022-08-22 16:57:26 |
| 2  | 1     | 345   | Subject2 | new    | 2022-08-22 13:24:09 |

tickets_handled

| id | queue | owner | subject  | priority | status |       created       |
| -- | ----- | ----- | -------- | -------- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 3  | 4     | 234   | Subject3 | 0        | open   | 2022-08-09 16:57:26 |
| 6  | 4     | 45    | Subject6 | 0        | open   | 2022-08-13 13:24:09 |

tickets_planworks

| id | subject    | status |       starts        |         due         |
| -- | ---------- | ------ | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 12 | Planworks1 | open   | 2022-08-23 21:01:00 | 2022-08-23 23:00:00 |
| 20 | Planworks2 | open   | 2022-08-23 21:01:00 | 2022-08-23 23:00:00 |
```

Then there's table objectcustomfieldvalues with structure:

```
objectcustomfieldvalues

| id | customfield | objectid | content              |
| -- | ----------- | -------- | -------------------- |
| 1  | 1           | 3        | Ticket3_Client       |
| 2  | 5           | 2        | Ticket2_Interaction  |
| 3  | 13          | 6        | Ticket6_Detalisation |

objectid links to id in tickets views
```

For example I try to join objectcustomfieldvalues with tickets_handled view with this query:

```
SELECT tt.id, tt.queue, tt.owner, tt.subject, tt.status, 
tt.created, 
cf_client.content AS client,
cf_interaction.content AS interaction,
cf_detalisation.content AS detalisation
FROM tickets_handled tt

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT objectid, content 
FROM objectcustomfieldvalues
WHERE objectid IN (SELECT id FROM tickets_handled)
AND customfield = '1') cf_client
ON cf_client.objectid=tt.id

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT objectid, content 
FROM objectcustomfieldvalues
WHERE objectid IN (SELECT id FROM tickets_handled)
AND customfield = '5') cf_interaction
ON cf_interaction.objectid=tt.id

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT objectid, content 
FROM objectcustomfieldvalues
WHERE objectid IN (SELECT id FROM tickets_handled)
AND customfield = '13') cf_detalisation
ON cf_detalisation.objectid=tt.id
```

And it results to table:

```
tickets_handled

| id | queue | owner | subject  | priority | status |       created       | client         | interaction | detalisation         |
| -- | ----- | ----- | -------- | -------- | ------ | ------------------- | -------------- | ----------- | -------------------- |
| 3  | 4     | 234   | Subject3 | 0        | open   | 2022-08-09 16:57:26 | Ticket3_Client |             |                      |
| 6  | 4     | 45    | Subject6 | 0        | open   | 2022-08-13 13:24:09 |                |             | Ticket6_Detalisation |
```

I want to have a procedure or somewhat where i can send a variable with view name (eg tickets_handled) and return table with fields from that view plus fields from table objectcustomfieldvalues linked to tickets in view.
Now when I write join query I have to mention all the fields for each of my views, also repeat view name in selects and write multiple joins for each customfield joined.